# Find the number of values associated with a key of dictionary and plot distplot

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, seaborn

Here I have a dictionary.

```
l= {31.2:array(['a']),
    35.1:array(['a','b','c']),
    36.4:array(['a','b'])}
```

So now as you can see the key 31.2 has 1 value, 35.1 has 3 values and 36.4 has 2 values. Now I want to plot the keys on x axis and length of its values along y axis. And maybe want to know whether it fits in normal distribution. If it doesn't fit , I want to know is there a possibility that I can fit this in normal distribution.

Comment: How many keys do you have in your dictionary? I'm presuming this is just an MWE and that you have more data in practice. I only ask because you'll need more data if you want to compare to a normal distribution.

Comment: There are about 1500 data points available for scatter plot suggested by you

Comment: I'd be tempted to just eyeball the points to consider whether or not they appear to be normally distributed. You could overlay a normal curve on the plot to help. Or, more statistically, you could take a look Kolmogorov-Smirnov or Shapiro-Wilks tests of normality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the plot as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import array

l = {31.2: array(['a']),
     35.1: array(['a', 'b', 'c']),
     36.4: array(['a', 'b'])}

# Get the length of each value
y = [value.size for value in l.values()]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

# Keys on the x-axis, length of value on the y-axis
ax.scatter(l.keys(), y)

ax.set_xlabel('Key')
ax.set_ylabel('Length of value')
```